# Why Won't Media Wiki Site Return Graphics To Browser and Have Correct Links Beyond 1st Page?

Tags: apache-2.2, mediawiki

My question is about MediaWiki configuration in the area of returning full URLs back to a front-end Apache server. Here is the description of the problem:

If I type in my MediaWiki's URL directly into my browser --  http://MyWikiServer:4409 -- everything works fine.

However, I want another Apache server -- that serves as a "web router" between the internet and inside our firewall -- to act as an internet front end to the wiki. This works for quite a few of our applications, but two things are happening with the Wiki which I am led to believe has something all or in part with the Wiki's configured server name. However, I am not sure about this fact.

1. The wiki's graphics are not being displayed correctly, and
2. Routes past the first page, which does display in text form, do not work; that is the links cannot be found.

Does any one have an idea of what could be configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "web-router" is more commonly called a Proxy.  (just FYI)  That beings said, whatever method you used to route the traffic is probably not forming the URLs properly... and so what hits the mediawiki as a URL gets garbled up in one way or another... and mediawiki cannot respond with an appropriate response.  I would check the logs to confirm this.